# Can import elements from tensorflow.python.keras, but not the module as a whole

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-import

How does the following python session make sense?

```
(ctlearn) jsevillamol@jsevillamol-N551JK:~/Documentos/ctlearn_keras$ python
Python 3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 13:39:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
>>> import tensorflow.python.keras as K
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

I can import `tensorflow.python.keras.models`, but not import `tensorflow.python.keras`.

What. I don't even.

Comment: Do you have maybe tensorflow.py file in your ctlearn_keras directory?

Comment: @opalczynski nope, in `ctlearn_keras` I have my git project source code, no libraries

Comment: Just checked - have the same :) Investigating.

Comment: Sry, have not time now, but it is interesting, anyway you can try: from tensorflow.python import keras as K